# Roth 401(k) Loan

Tags: united-states, income-tax, retirement-plan

I am thinking about taking out a loan from the Roth 401(k) plan. The idea behind the loan is to put more money into the Roth 401(k). I would like to charge myself a very high rate of interest, say 20%, but I do not think that would fly with the IRS. 
Please comment.

Comment: You are not defining the interest rate; they do. And it will be lower than typical market performance.

Comment: Is this a Solo 401(k)?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Yes it is.